# Objective C collection operators - Getting the average 'array count' in a 2D array

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

I'm trying to use KVC collection to get the average count of arrays in a collection. In other words, my data structure looks like this `@[ @[...], @[......], @[..] ]` and I am trying to average the count of the internal arrays.

I could do it the old fashion way, but it seems like something KVC collection operators might be able to help with -- unfortunately i can't get it to work.

It seems like this would be the right syntax:

> NSNumber *avg = [topLevelArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.count"]

Yet this draws an exception -- claiming that the objects contained within the second level of arrays are not KVC compliant for the key 'count'.

Is there a way to run KVC collection operators on second level arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the proper `@count` collection operator [tested]:

```
NSNumber *avg = [topLevelArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.@count"];
```